# How to create server and client socket on a single different thread

Tags: android, sockets

I am working on Android GPS library. I need to create a separate thread in the library that keeps running continuously after creating client and server sockets.

Similarly I create sockets in the Java application that sends values to the library code on user interaction.

How do I create such socket in GPS library and in the application so that they keep running continuously? Basically I want the socket in GPS library in different thread so that it never stops.

Eagerly waiting for your replies....

Comment: What have you tried so far? Or do you expect somebody to just write it for you?

Comment: Note that there's no way to guarantee that it never stops.  And holding a wakelock is a good way to kill the battery.  But even that won't guarantee your thread never stops, as if its in the background it can be killed for resources, and if it's in the foreground it can be killed when the platform foolishly tries to resume a background service it previously killed for resources and so runs out of memory...

Comment: I have tried to communicate using sockets. On Java end, I tried DataOutputStream.writeUTF and on the C end, I was receiving the stream using recv(). The return value for recv is a positive integer, but the buffer is always empty!!!

Answer (score -1):

get a look into services, especially remote services, they run on separate thread each one.

also if you need to run a special code on other thread inside your main app use the new Runnable(), it runs the same code you put into there but within a separate thread.

Comment: Services don't run on a separate thread. They run on a different thread than other processes, but if you block the main thread, you'll get an ANR.